# Why does my custom spaCy entity type get detected?

Tags: named-entity-recognition, spacy

I am writing a [spaCy](https://spacy.io/) program for which I want to define a custom named entity tag. Following the example [here](https://spacy.io/usage/training#example-new-entity-type), I add a label called `MY_NEW_LABEL` to the pipeline.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")
new_label = "MY_NEW_LABEL"
ner.add_label(new_label)

documents_path = "my_document.txt"
document = nlp(open(documents_path).read())
print([e for e in document.ents if e.label_ == new_label])
```

When I run the above program it prints out a list of entities labeled with `MY_NEW_LABEL`. I don't see how this is possible because I never do anything with the label.

Clearly I'm misunderstanding how to work with custom entity tags, but I can't figure out why this would be happening from the documentation. Can anyone tell me why my program doesn't print out an empty list?

Comment: Hi, I'm one of the spaCy maintainers – this is indeed very confusing, and might indicate a bug. Would you mind opening an issue on our [issue tracker](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues) and include some examples of the texts and entities that are recognised for the new label? Would love to try reproducing the error and get to the bottom of this!

Comment: I will. The text I'm currently seeing it on is proprietary, but I think any sufficiently long text will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unexpected behavior. I opened it as spaCy issue [1697: Custom Entity Labels Are Erroneously Detected](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1697).